# Ionic/Firebase app on Android is redirecting to localhost

Tags: android, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I have an Ionic app with Firebase Authentication enabled for Google. signInWithPopup() works great in Browser. But when I build and run on Android, using signInWithRedirect(), Chrome redirects to localhost instead of back to the Android app.

Ionic 6.17.1
Firebase 9.20.0

I'm new to this, and I'm sure I'm missing something simple - any help is greatly appreciated.

```
GoogleAuth() {
  this.socialSignIn(new GoogleAuthProvider());
}

socialSignIn(provider): Promise<any> {

  if (this.platform.is('desktop')) {
    return signInWithPopup(this.auth, provider).then(result => {
      console.log('social login success');
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log('social login error', error);
    })
  } else {
    // web but not desktop, for example mobile PWA
    return signInWithRedirect(this.auth, provider).then(result => {
      console.log('social login success');
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log('social login error', error);
    })
  }
}
```